# Cascade update not triggered

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have 2 domain classes. ParentDomain and Section.

```
class ParentDomain {
    String description
    List sections
    static hasMany = [sections:Section]
}



class Section {

    String name
    static belongsTo = [parentDomain : ParentDomain]
}
```

In the service method when I set(for the first time) parentDomain.setSections(list of section objects) it saves it properly with the following content in the section table.

```
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| id | version | name          | parentdomain_id | sections_idx |
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
|  1 |       0 | Section 1     |           6     |        0     |
|  2 |       0 | Section 1     |           6     |       0      |
+----+---------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

When I get/update the parent domain object from the DB and set list of new section objects parentDomain.setSections(list of new section objects) and then run parentDomain.save(flush:true) it does not remove the old section objects from the table but adds the new section entries in addition to the old one's like this.

```
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| id | version | name          | parentdomain_id | sections_idx |
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
|  1 |       0 | Section 1     |           6     |        0     |
|  2 |       0 | Section 2     |           6     |        1     |
|  3 |       0 | Section 3     |           6     |        0     |
|  4 |       0 | Section 4     |           6     |        1     |
+----+---------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

As far as I understand it should only persist 2 section objects while updating and remove the old ones due to cascade update. Its also strange that when I fetch parent domain object instance from db I only get the last 2 section objects associated with it. Is it because of sections_idx ?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are using incorrect way of adding data in the `hasMany` property. Instead of using `setSections()` method, you should use `addToSections()` method ([addTo*](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/addTo.html)).

And removing is not automated (unless otherwise you are auto-binding (not sure with this List scenario)). You have to manually remove child objects from parent using `removeFromSections()` method ([removeFrom*](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/removeFrom.html)).

**Edit_____________________________________________________________**

I don't know the internal process of these methods, but `addToSections` method is a simple setter method, which does not have to do with the state of the table. And hence in your case it again starts from `0` in `sections_idx` column independent of this that this index is already exists (*_idx column is most important column when we use List in hasMany, like in your case. It maintains the index of the child in the list.) and therefore second time you got two instances in `parentDomain.sections` instead of four.

While `*addTo` method (GORM) helps maintaining the index of the new entries by `_idx` look up from the table.

And setter cannot remove parent-child association, `removeFrom*` is meant for that.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Actually, I have been using GORM since few weeks only. I mostly use hibernate Pojo's for data persistence. I am aware of addTo and removeFrom* but I don't understand why set method is incorrect way as I wanted to overwrite the collection. I think addTo* will append to the existing list.  Also in hibernate if we overwrite a collection the old collection gets deleted. I expected GORM to work that way as it is also built on top of hibernate.

Comment: I understood the significance of idx column. List preserves the order so it needs to add _idx column to maintain that. I will look into it more deeply and compare it with hibernate. Thanks Manish ;) +1 for your answer